# 2 images in 1st row and 3 images in 2nd row using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, staggered-gridview

How to make a `staggeredGridView` in flutter which have 2 rows . In first row there will be two images and in second row there will be three images and in last image of the 2nd row there will be some text like 20+ or 40+.

 have a look at the following image for better understanding

[image]

```
body: Padding(
        child: Container
         (
          height: 1500,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          child: StaggeredGridView.count(

            crossAxisCount: 4,
            mainAxisSpacing: 3.0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 3.0,
            staggeredTiles: [
              StaggeredTile.count(2, 1),
              StaggeredTile.count(2, 1),
              StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
              StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
              StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
              StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),

            ],

            children: <Widget>[
              myPhotoList(
                  "https://www.google.com/search?q=bird&rlz=1C1CHBD_enBD884BD884&sxsrf=ALeKk032QyXLy5s0te6Y52Sp3yyA2g4sfQ:1598990850500&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjslZKN4cjrAhUWWX0KHe3sAdMQ_AUoAXoECB0QAw&biw=1536&bih=792#imgrc=1ois95B-LwbEBM"),
              myPhotoList(
                  "https://www.google.com/search?q=bird&rlz=1C1CHBD_enBD884BD884&sxsrf=ALeKk032QyXLy5s0te6Y52Sp3yyA2g4sfQ:1598990850500&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjslZKN4cjrAhUWWX0KHe3sAdMQ_AUoAXoECB0QAw&biw=1536&bih=792#imgrc=1ois95B-LwbEBM"),
              myPhotoList(
                  "https://www.google.com/search?q=bird&rlz=1C1CHBD_enBD884BD884&sxsrf=ALeKk032QyXLy5s0te6Y52Sp3yyA2g4sfQ:1598990850500&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjslZKN4cjrAhUWWX0KHe3sAdMQ_AUoAXoECB0QAw&biw=1536&bih=792#imgrc=1ois95B-LwbEBM"),
              myPhotoList(
                  "https://www.google.com/search?q=bird&rlz=1C1CHBD_enBD884BD884&sxsrf=ALeKk032QyXLy5s0te6Y52Sp3yyA2g4sfQ:1598990850500&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjslZKN4cjrAhUWWX0KHe3sAdMQ_AUoAXoECB0QAw&biw=1536&bih=792#imgrc=1ois95B-LwbEBM"),
              myPhotoList(
                  "https://www.google.com/search?q=bird&rlz=1C1CHBD_enBD884BD884&sxsrf=ALeKk032QyXLy5s0te6Y52Sp3yyA2g4sfQ:1598990850500&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjslZKN4cjrAhUWWX0KHe3sAdMQ_AUoAXoECB0QAw&biw=1536&bih=792#imgrc=1ois95B-LwbEBM"),
              myPhotoList(
                  "https://www.google.com/search?q=bird&rlz=1C1CHBD_enBD884BD884&sxsrf=ALeKk032QyXLy5s0te6Y52Sp3yyA2g4sfQ:1598990850500&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjslZKN4cjrAhUWWX0KHe3sAdMQ_AUoAXoECB0QAw&biw=1536&bih=792#imgrc=1ois95B-LwbEBM"),
              Details(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
 ),

Widget myPhotoList(String img) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          image: NetworkImage(
              img),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: it will be awesome if you add some of the code you tried that will encourage the community to answer , anyway i'll try to do something for you

Comment: Thanks. I have added some code. In that way, I manageg to add 2 images in 1st row and 4 images in 2nd row. But failed to add 3 images in 2nd row instead of 4 images

Comment: "A Flutter staggered grid view which supports multiple columns with rows of varying sizes." is the definition of this plugin on pub.dev. Yet you want something that is very much static and predefined (1st row = 2 columns, 2nd row = 3 columns). So IMHO for you the best solution isn't to get the `staggeredGridView` to conform to your very specific needs, but to change the _tool_ you are using, you can get exactly what you are looking for with 2 very basic widgets: `Column` and `Row`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
body: Container(
        height: 1500,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: StaggeredGridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 6,
          mainAxisSpacing: 3.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 3.0,
          staggeredTiles: [
            StaggeredTile.count(3, 2),
            StaggeredTile.count(3, 2),
            StaggeredTile.count(2, 2),
            StaggeredTile.count(2, 2),
            StaggeredTile.count(2, 2),
            // StaggeredTile.count(1, 1),
          ],
          children: <Widget>[
            myPhotoList(
                "https://www.google.com/search?q=bird&rlz=1C1CHBD_enBD884BD884&sxsrf=ALeKk032QyXLy5s0te6Y52Sp3yyA2g4sfQ:1598990850500&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjslZKN4cjrAhUWWX0KHe3sAdMQ_AUoAXoECB0QAw&biw=1536&bih=792#imgrc=1ois95B-LwbEBM"),
            myPhotoList(
                "https://www.google.com/search?q=bird&rlz=1C1CHBD_enBD884BD884&sxsrf=ALeKk032QyXLy5s0te6Y52Sp3yyA2g4sfQ:1598990850500&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjslZKN4cjrAhUWWX0KHe3sAdMQ_AUoAXoECB0QAw&biw=1536&bih=792#imgrc=1ois95B-LwbEBM"),
            myPhotoList(
                "https://www.google.com/search?q=bird&rlz=1C1CHBD_enBD884BD884&sxsrf=ALeKk032QyXLy5s0te6Y52Sp3yyA2g4sfQ:1598990850500&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjslZKN4cjrAhUWWX0KHe3sAdMQ_AUoAXoECB0QAw&biw=1536&bih=792#imgrc=1ois95B-LwbEBM"),
            myPhotoList(
                "https://www.google.com/search?q=bird&rlz=1C1CHBD_enBD884BD884&sxsrf=ALeKk032QyXLy5s0te6Y52Sp3yyA2g4sfQ:1598990850500&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjslZKN4cjrAhUWWX0KHe3sAdMQ_AUoAXoECB0QAw&biw=1536&bih=792#imgrc=1ois95B-LwbEBM"),
            myPhotoList(
                "https://www.google.com/search?q=bird&rlz=1C1CHBD_enBD884BD884&sxsrf=ALeKk032QyXLy5s0te6Y52Sp3yyA2g4sfQ:1598990850500&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjslZKN4cjrAhUWWX0KHe3sAdMQ_AUoAXoECB0QAw&biw=1536&bih=792#imgrc=1ois95B-LwbEBM"),
            //myPhotoList(
            //  "https://www.google.com/search?q=bird&rlz=1C1CHBD_enBD884BD884&sxsrf=ALeKk032QyXLy5s0te6Y52Sp3yyA2g4sfQ:1598990850500&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjslZKN4cjrAhUWWX0KHe3sAdMQ_AUoAXoECB0QAw&biw=1536&bih=792#imgrc=1ois95B-LwbEBM"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: ah! Thanks Shuvo . I don't know why I didn't think like that way. It's just a LCM which solves my problem. Thanks again